# Unable to retrieve nodes from remote instance -- Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

[image: 1]

I'm new to NIFI (Still learning) We have a process flow that is executing till today morning without any issues and since today morning all the messages got queued up and throwing the below error in nifi.

Unable to retrieve nodes from remote instance
15:04:30 NZDTWARNINGcb7f3de5-1ca5-12d2-88f3-8899ede30d22
shapserver3.test.com:9443 Unable to refresh remote group peers due to: Unable to retrieve nodes from remote instance

When checked the logs on the server node, we could see the below error and not sure what exactly is the issue. Can someone help?

2023-02-13 13:27:57,134 WARN [Http Site-to-Site PeerSelector] o.apache.nifi.remote.client.PeerSelector Could not communicate with nifi2.analytics-prod.cloud.com:443 to determine which node(s) exist in the remote NiFi instance, due to javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

checked the logs but i do not understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

This means the truststore of the current NiFi does not trust the certificate presented by the remote NiFI at nifi2.analytics-prod.cloud.com. Meaning, nifi2.analytics-prod.cloud.com presented a certificate that was signed by a CA that is not in the truststore of the other NiFi instance.